# How to do a left-join on a data variable's values using xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Imagine having a dataset of shipments where every `shipID` can contain multiple products:

```py
In [2]: shipDS
Out[2]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (shipID: 6)
Coordinates:
  * shipID      (shipID) int64 1 1 2 3 4 4
Data variables:
    prodID      (shipID) int64 90 91 92 90 90 91
    qtyShipped  (shipID) int64 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

In a separate dataset, each product has some stored attributes (name, weight, etc.):

```
In [3]: prodDS
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (prodID: 4)
Coordinates:
  * prodID      (prodID) int64 90 91 92 93
Data variables:
    prodName    (prodID) <U8 'Almonds' 'Berries' 'Candy' 'Dog Food'
    prodWeight  (prodID) float64 0.5 1.5 1.0 12.0
```

I love xarray and want to use it as much as possible without reverting to Pandas.  However, I cannot seem to answer a very basic question in the scenario above, namely "how much did each shipment weigh?"

Here is the code to replicate the two datasets:

```python
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset({"a": ("index", list("xyzxyzxy"))})
other = xr.Dataset({"a": list("xz"), "b": ("a", [1, 2])})

## construct dataset of shipments
## each shipment might have multiple products
shipIDs = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
productIDs = [90,91,92,90,90,91]
quantity = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

shipDS = xr.Dataset(data_vars = 
    {
        "prodID": ("shipID", productIDs),
        "qtyShipped": ("shipID", quantity)
    },
    coords = {
        "shipID": shipIDs
    }
)

## construct product info dataset
prodID = [90,91,92,93]
prodName = ["Almonds","Berries","Candy","Dog Food"]
prodWeight = [0.5,1.5,1.0,12]

prodDS = xr.Dataset(data_vars = 
    {
        "prodName": ("prodID", prodName),
        "prodWeight": ("prodID", prodWeight)
    },
    coords = {
        "prodID": prodID
    }
)

## MOTIVATING QUESTION: HOW MUCH WEIGHT WAS IN EACH SHIPMENT?
## PART I AM STUCK ON IS JUST JOINING THE DATASETS.  HELP APPRECIATED!
```

In one's head, it is easy to imagine how to find the total weight for each shipID.

Using `merge` like

```
shipDS.set_coords("prodID").merge(prodDS).to_dataframe()
```

seems to require making `prodID` a coordinate to work which expands the space to be way too big; shipID should be the only coordinate/dimension and "dog food" should not be part of the new dataset as it was never shipped.

Here is the code to get an answer using pandas:

```py
In [5]: ## ANSWER USING PANDAS
   ...: (
   ...:     shipDS   ## start with shipment dataset
   ...:     .to_dataframe()  ## convert ot pandas df
   ...:     .join(prodDS.to_dataframe(), on="prodID")   #left join with product info df
   ...:     .reset_index()  # reset index
   ...:     .groupby("shipID")  # group by shipID
   ...:     .agg(totalWt = ("prodWeight", sum))  # get total weight
   ...: )
Out[5]:
        totalWt
shipID
1           2.0
2           1.0
3           0.5
4           2.0
```

How can this be done without reverting to pandas?

Comment: since you're interested in an xaray-based answer, could you actually show your datasets as xarray objects rather than the result of `.to_pandas`? it would be a lot easier for us to sort out how this will work knowing what the actual dims/variables/coords are. also, can you paste the result of `print(ds)` as a code block rather than an image? stack overflow asks that we please not upload images of code/data/logs/etc [for a variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/). Thanks!

Comment: I did a bit of restructuring to make the question (I think) a bit more clear and useful to a wider audience. feel free to [review the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74318816/revisions) and [edit]/revert if you think I mis-represented anything about your question or if you think it could be more clear.

Comment: You @MichaelDelgado are a genius and a hero.  Thanks so much for the edits.  I still use `to_pandas` to digest the data because I am bad at vector recycling (broadcasting?) in my head.

Comment: ha! thanks - glad it helped! credit definitely goes to the xarray developers for this magic though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xarray's [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) rules to reindex `prodDS` to conform to the dimensions of `shipDS`:

```py
In [4]: products_shipped = prodDS.sel(prodID=shipDS.prodID)
   ...: products_shipped
Out[4]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (shipID: 6)
Coordinates:
    prodID      (shipID) int64 90 91 92 90 90 91
  * shipID      (shipID) int64 1 1 2 3 4 4
Data variables:
    prodName    (shipID) <U8 'Almonds' 'Berries' 'Candy' ... 'Almonds' 'Berries'
    prodWeight  (shipID) float64 0.5 1.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 1.5
```

This happens because the indexer, `shipDS.prodID`, is a `DataVariable`. Under the Advanced Indexing rules, if you select using a DataArary, the *values* of the indexing DataArray are used to select/reshape the data along the selected dataset's dimensions (`prodID`), but the *dimensions and coordinates* of the indexing DataArray (`shipID`) will be used as the dimensions and coordinates of the result! So now we have product names and weights by `shipID`! Notice that this is exactly a left join in the pandas sense - we have all the elements of `prodDS`, reindexed to match the product IDs present on each ship in `shipDS`.

Now, using this reindexed result, the weight carried on each ship is a simple product:

```py
In [6]: shipDS.qtyShipped * products_shipped.prodWeight
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray (shipID: 6)>
array([0.5, 1.5, 1. , 0.5, 0.5, 1.5])
Coordinates:
  * shipID   (shipID) int64 1 1 2 3 4 4
    prodID   (shipID) int64 90 91 92 90 90 91
```

And voila! Now you can love xarray even more ;)